# Cache misses from random access array

Tags: c++

I have an array of values corresponding to an integer indexed axis. I need to linearly interpolate from these values at specific double precision indices.

```
double indices[20];
double results[20];
double values[1000];

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    double index = indices[i];
    int indexInt = (int)index; 
    double frac = index - indexInt;

    // Linear interpolation
    result[i] = values[indexInt] * (1.0 - frac) + values[indexInt + 1] * frac;
}
```

Profiling shows that the result linear interpolation line is taking more program run time than expected, and my suspicion is that this is due to cache misses. The indices are sorted but not guaranteed to be close to each other, and do not have a constant stride. Is there a way to mitigate this?

Comment: You did enable the optimizer?

Comment: @manni66 Of course, would be no point in profiling otherwise

Comment: Are your `double` arrays global? It looks about as cache-friendly as it gets.

Comment: Did you use a tool like perf to measure the number of cache misses? Imo it looks quite good from a cache perspective

Comment: @nwp My arrays are private class members. This whole thing is encapsulated inside a class.

Comment: @Christoph haven't tried that, sounds like a good idea

Comment: Lerp can be simplified to `(A-B)*t+B` instead of `A*t + B*(1-t)`, which is one less multiplication operation. Compiler might be already doing it for you but worth a shot.

Comment: Any chance to change `indices` from `double` to `int` or `std::size_t`? Arguably indexes should not be `double`s.

Comment: @nwp The whole point is to get linear interpolation. The indices are more akin to values on an axis. I store the whole curve at integer values of the axis, and linearly interpolate to any real value within. That's accurate enough for my implementation, but using integer values would not be

Comment: Could you sort the indices array? That might help  reuse information in the values array.

Comment: @dwwork indices array is already sorted, sorry that I failed to mention that

Comment: If it is a problem with cache misses, it might be mitigate-able from the outside. Is it possible to lump similar calls together?

Comment: At a first look, the slowest operation is the `(int)index` line. I think we'd need a more complete benchmark code to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: do you use `values` several times, or only once? If you use it only once, then it can be a cache issue. On the other hand, if you use it a lot of times, this is definitely not a cache issue (`values` is a 8k array, should fit in the cache).

Comment: @EyalK. would highly suggest making `indicies` an array of `int` or `size_t` that way the CPU can do proper prefetching long before it gets to the rest of the code. Because `indicies` is pre-calculated you should be able to do the proper `floor` operation once, or better yet round it appropriately.

Comment: @Mgetz indices must be double, since the whole point of this is to do linear interpolation to the accurate value

Comment: @EyalK. you're missing the point, you're `flooring` them anyway and they are precalculated. Making them double just delays the conversion until it causes the prefetcher trouble. Since they are precalulated you can preconvert them too.

Comment: @Mgetz I am flooring them, but still using the double value for linear interpolation